# Detecting Combinations In Array Elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making a tictactoe game which runs on array `blocks` where `-` represent an empty block (square) and `x`/`o` represent each piece. In tictactoe there are 8 total ways of winning. What I'm trying to do is have 8 variables being checked  to see if anyone has one yet.

**Examples:**

One winning condition would be `blocks[0]`, `blocks[1]`, and `blocks[2]` all `=== 'x'` For a horizontal line at the top,

Or a diagonal line from bottom left to top right (`blocks[6]`, `blocks[4]`, `blocks[2]` all `=== 'x'`)

```
const blocks = 
   [
      '-', '-', '-',
      '-', '-', '-',
      '-', '-', '-'
   ]
```

For 2 elements I would just do `blocks[num] === 'x' && blocks[num2] === 'x'` But how can I check for 3 elements?

Comment: Why not just do 
((blocks[num] === 'x' ) && (blocks[num2] === 'x') && (blocks[num3] === 'x'))

Comment: I thought `&&` only takes 2 expressions(?)

Comment: Nope you can do as many comparisons as you want.

Answer (score 1):

check out the code sample below that will save you time when it comes to dealing with multiple if conditions. It is tailored towards you problem. The function basically takes any size of a square block for tic-tac-toe and a character to check if it has won. Hope this helps.

```js
var blocks = [
  'o', 'o', 'x',
  'x', 'o', 'x',
  'x', 'x', 'o'
]

/**
 function takes a board (assumes its a perfect square and the character 
 to be compared and returns true if it is the winner. 
 ie. has characters in a continuous straight
**/
function checkWinner(board, char) {

  var boardSize = board.length;
  var lineLength = Math.sqrt(boardSize); // the length of a straight line wheter vertical, horizontal or diagnoal 

  // compare horizontals 
  for (var i = 0; i < lineLength; i++) {
    var hWin = true;
    for (var j = (i * lineLength); j < ((i * lineLength) + lineLength); j++) {
      if (board[j] !== char) {
        hWin = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (hWin == true) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  //    // compare verticals    
  for (var i = 0; i < lineLength; i++) {
    var vWin = true;
    for (var j = i; j <= (boardSize - (lineLength - i)); j += lineLength) {
      if (board[j] !== char) {
        vWin = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (vWin == true) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  // compare diagonals
  /* top left to bottom right */
  var diag1Win = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < lineLength; i++) {
    if (board[(i * lineLength) + i] !== char) {
      diag1Win = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (diag1Win == true) {
    return true;
  }

  /* top right to bottom left */
  var diag2Win = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < lineLength; i++) {
    if (board[((i * lineLength) - i) + (lineLength - 1)] !== char) {
      diag2Win = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (diag2Win == true) {
    return true;
  }

  return false; // no win
}
checkWinner(blocks, 'o')
```